# Change Background color of React Native NativeModules.UIManager.showPopupMenu

Tags: reactjs, react-native

can we change the background color of NativeModules.UIManager.showPopupMenu menu ? It shows white background by default. I'm creating an app which has darker theme so need to chnage the background color.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can do this with some simple changes.

Your React theme should have these 2 properties :

```
<style name="ReactAppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.DayNight.NoActionBar">
    <!-- if using android.widget.PopupMenu -->
    <item name="android:popupMenuStyle">@style/PopupMenu</item>
    <!-- if using android.support.v7.widget.PopupMenu -->
    <item name="popupMenuStyle">@style/PopupMenu</item>
</style>
```

and then define your PopupMenu theme like this :

```
<style name="PopupMenu" parent="Theme.AppCompat.DayNight">
    <item name="android:textColor">some color</item>
    <item name="android:colorBackground">some color</item>
    <item name="android:popupBackground">some color</item>
</style>
```